# Linux : Error during parsing: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, linux, encoding, utf-8, locale

I am working on a Debian system where I have to block a list of IP addresses. When I am using the program 'iblocklist2ipset' to do so, I am getting the following error.

```
[0/16] Error during parsing: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
[1/16] Error during parsing: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
[2/16] Error during parsing: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
[3/16] Error during parsing: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

As I checked, this has got something to do with Python and locales. I am not that much acquainted with Python, but I reconfigured by locales just to be on safe side and rebooted the machine, but no use. Currently, output of Locale is as follows :

```
user:/home/deploy# locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Is there something wrong I am doing. kindly let me know how I can solve this. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: Why was this question marked for close down. A comment would be appreciated. The solutions on net are not working for me...I have already tried them.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help you understand your problem in detail.
Check here: 
[ordinal not in range(128)](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-does-unicodeerror-ascii-decoding-encoding-error-ordinal-not-in-range-128-mean.htm)

Comment: I got the problem, but how can I apply some setting system wide, so this problem does not happen when I call the program?

Comment: You can switch to python 3.x where all strings are unicode by default and bytes and bytearrays are the all ascii strings. There might be incompatibilities with some scripts but I think this will do the trick for you .

Answer (score 0):

When you run iblocklist2ipset and fetch the URL, make sure, you remove the "gz" in there, as you will the data as text.
This works until the make a patch

Answer (score 0):

The error happends because data was compressed with 'gzip'.
You have to change 'network.py' to decompress the coming stream and it will work.